# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i'm trying to add roomSchema to a userSchema

this is my code

```
router.post('/join-room', async (req, res) => {
  const { roomId, userId } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const room = await Room.findById(roomId);
    if (!user || !room) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User or room not found' });
    }
    user.rooms.push(roomId);
    await user.save();
    res.json({ message: 'User joined room successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

this my user schema ,i added room model to my userSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Room" }
});
```

this is my json

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6436c40c989d571ad31563a8"),
  name: 'jquery',
  email: 'a@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$10$fdPk3EzPPZc4SDxGmYnj3usFm9IlU0SNb.Ek4hINXHTfNSAclscxW',
  __v: 0
} {
  _id: new ObjectId("6436bf25f70ece2db5576081"),
  created_date: 2023-04-12T14:24:37.439Z,
  name: 'vue',
  __v: 0
}
```

this my error

```
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: Please share your schemas for `User` and `Room`.

Comment: Well, seems your `User` does not have a `rooms` property or it's set to `undefined` for that particular user.

Comment: `console.log(user)` and see what it is

Comment: @cmgchess it looks like they already shared that above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `room` property is not set to be an array in your schema. To fix that, surround it in `[]`.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  room: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Room" }] // Here
});
```

Your code also is using `user.rooms` and not `user.room`, so you'll either need to make the property above plural or make your usage singular.

Comment: Still getting Same error.

Comment: See updated note